# while Connecting java webservice to snowflake i am getting error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

hostname=jdbc:snowflake://y.ap-south-1.aws.snowflakecomputing.com/
user=
password=
account=y.ap-south-1
database=DEMO_DB

warehouse=COMPUTE_WH
schema=PUBLIC

**this is my connection.properties**
Every time i got incorrect username or password was specified

Comment: Are you able to connect using same details with Snowflake UI? Can you generate [JDBC logs](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#JDBC) and see what is happening?

Comment: Yes I have used same credentials for both

Comment: The JDBC logs would help in this case. Can you also try with account=y without the region?

Comment: By any chance is this user coming from a SSO entity? Like Okta or Azure AD?

Comment: user is coming from azure ad

Comment: snowflake account use azure ad

Comment: What about JDBC log? Have you manage to get it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that you are passing the username coming from Azure AD to Snowflake and expecting it to be authenticated with "snowflake" auth mechanism.
In the connection string, pass the following parameter as well:

```
authenticator=externalbrowser
```

What this will do is to open a browser session where you can then authenticate the user from AAD and session will pass the auth check.

Comment: I put authenticator string in connection file but I got JNA files are needed for secure storage. Which version I need to use